# Laravel database Design and Relationship

Tags: laravel, datatable, eloquent, foreign-key-relationship

I want to create my own payment system. There are 3 model transactions in my system:

1. from bank to user account on site
2. from user account on site to another user account on site
3. from user account on site to user credit cart

Can anyone help me to create relationships and tables?
How can I trace money workflow with the database?

After one day I got to these tables:

```
Schema::create('transactiondep', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('Fromid');
            $table->integer('Toid');
            $table->string('Timestamp');    
        });

Schema::create('transactionlog', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('Userid');
            $table->integer('Credit');
            $table->integer('Categoryid');
            $table->integer('Request_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('Description')->nullable();
            $table->string('Timestamp');
        });
```

Example : user 45 paid 90 dollor to user 73;

transactionlog record:

```
id=1 || userid=45 || credit=-90 || categoryid=9 || Requestid=null || Description=null 

id=2 || userid=73 || credit=+90 || categoryid=9 || Requestid=null || Description=null
```

transactiondep record:

```
id=1 || fromid=45 || toid=73
```

What is wrong with my table?